# Creating a Two Screen Kivy menu - changing picture and label from selection

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a two screen Kivy touchscreen interface on a Raspberry Pi that acts like a selectable Menu interface to do a function depending on the Selection.

Screen 1: 
Shows Eight Blocks - each block is made up by a BoxLayout that consists of Label, Image, Timer, Button.

Screen 2:
A pre defined list of blocks with names and pictures and a timer value.

Now lets say I want block 2 on screen one to have its values set to whatever I select on Screen2, I would like to press on the Button of Block2 on screen 1, it opens screen2 and I select one of the items. Now depending on what I selected on screen2, it should now load the values of that item and update block 2 on screen1 with Label, Image, Timer. The Timer should be a countdown timer.

I have the basic Layout that works showing screen1 and screen2 but am batteling with the value update concept and the multiple Blocks. The Code is still a bit of a mess but hope it gives an idea of what I am trying to do - will past it after posting the question. Screen Two still  has no values..

## main.py

```
# class for aqua.kv file
class MainScreen(Screen):
        pass

# class for screen.kv file
class SelectScreen(Screen):
        pass

class Tray1(Screen):
        pass
# class for date.kv file
class Date(BoxLayout,EventDispatcher):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Date,self).__init__(**kwargs)


Builder.load_file('date.kv')
Builder.load_file('tray1.kv')
class MyApp(App):
        time = StringProperty()

        def update(self,*args):
                self.time = str(time.asctime())

        def build(self):
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1)
                # Set up the layout:

                return Builder.load_file('screen.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

## screen.kv

```
ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        MainScreen:
                id: main_screen
                name: 'MainScreen'
                manager: 'screen_manager'

        SelectScreen:
                id: select_screen
                name: 'SelectScreen'
                manager: 'screen_manager'
#       on_release: background_color = 1,0,0,1
<MainScreen>:
        BoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                        Color:
                                rgba: .5,.6,.7,1
                        Rectangle:
                                pos: self.pos
                                size: self.size
                orientation:'vertical'
                BoxLayout:
                        size_hint:1,.2
                        Date:
                BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
#               size_hint: .2,1
                        BoxLayout:
                                orientation: 'vertical'
                                Label:
                                        id:btn_tray1
                                        font_size: 30
                                Image:
                                        source:"logo.png"
                                Tray1:
                                Button:
                                        id:btn_tray1_1
                                        font_size: 30
                                        text:"Tray1"
                                        on_release: app.root.current = "SelectScreen"
                                #on_release: app.root.current = "SelectScreen"
                #       on_release: btn_tray1.background_color = 1,0,0,1
                        Button:
                                id:btn_tray2
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray2"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "SelectScreen"
                        Button:
                                id: btn_tray3
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray3"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "SelectScreen"

<SelectScreen>:
        BoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                        Color:
                                rgba: .5,.6,.7,1
                        Rectangle:
                                pos: self.pos
                                size: self.size
                orientation:'vertical'
                BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                #       size_hint: .2,1
                        Button:
                                size_hint:1,.2
                                id:btn_tray5
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray5"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "MainScreen"
                #       on_release: btn_tray1.background_color = 1,0,0,1
                        Button:
                                size_hint:1,.2
                                id:btn_tray6
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray6"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "MainScreen"
                        Button:
                                size_hint:1,.2
                                id: btn_tray7
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray7"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "MainScreen"
                #       on_release: btn_tray3.background_color = 1,0,0,1
                        Button:
                                size_hint:1,.2
                                id: btn_tray8
                                font_size: 30
                                text:"Tray8"
                                on_release: app.root.current = "MainScreen"
                #       on_release: btn_tray4.background_color = 1,0,0,1
```

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are both those `kv` sections part of the same `screen.kv`?

Comment: You need to clearly state what you expect your code to do, and what it is doing instead of that. Like, `Click on this and that should happen, but this other thing happens`

Comment: @JohnAnderson  Yes, both kv sections are part of the same screen.kv

Comment: @JohnAnderson I am trying build a timer interface. By default on screen one all eight boxes should show nothing but only a label like LED1.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I am trying build a timer interface. By default on screen one all eight boxes should show nothing but only a label like LED1. Screen 2 should have a selection of boxes defined like : Name, image, and a Time Value.  After selecting like box three on screen one and then choosing one of the defined boxes on screen two, the box three on screen one should then show: Label: The name, the image , a countdown of the Time Value of that defined box.

Comment: Well, you are quite a ways from that goal right now. All you buttons merely switch the current screen. I suggest writing some code for the buttons to execute. And for a timer, I can recommend [this widget](https://github.com/DaytonaJohn/KivyDigitalClock). (Full disclosure: I wrote it.)

Comment: @JohnAnderson Very true - quite far from my goal :-)  . The code snipped is purely the screen layout. I had no clue on how to continue, but I think I solved my puzzle and the way forward.  Using SringProperty variables and couple of definitions etc.  Slightly starting to understand Kivy .   Very nice clock you wrote. Basically locking for something like an egg timer. Do something until timer gets to zero. But I think I might get a hang of it.